# Replace 'e' modifier with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to replace this:

```
$source = preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/me', "utf8_encode(chr(\\1))", $source);
```

with `preg_replace_callback` and an anonymous function.

What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '/&#(\d+);/m',
    function ($matches) {
        return utf8_encode(chr($matches[1]));
    },
    $source
);
```

Comment: You're right - and I love Short Circuit, tho

Comment: You're welcome @Sight if you consider this the right answer don't forget to mark it as correct answer :)